# Pin Toggle button style

Tags: wpf, xaml, togglebutton

Hi i want to create a generic style for pin button.

```
<Window x:Class="TooglePinButtonStyle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="pinImage"
           Width="14"
           Height="14"
           Source="/TooglePinButtonStyle;component/Images/pin.png" />
    <Image x:Key="unPinImage"
           Width="14"
           Height="14"
           Source="/TooglePinButtonStyle;component/Images/unpin.png" />

    <Style x:Key="pinButtonStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
      <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource unPinImage}" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource pinImage}" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton Height="30" 
                  Width="30"
                  Style="{StaticResource pinButtonStyle}"/>
    <ToggleButton Height="30" 
                  Width="30" 
                  Style="{StaticResource pinButtonStyle}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

It works fine when there is only one button but when I have two button the UI crashes with

> "Specified element is already the logical child of another element.
>   Disconnect it first."

exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the images [non-shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx), or set the `ContentTemplate` to some `DataTemplate` which contains an image (not a reference to an image), rather than the `Content`. If you have only one instance of an UI-element you will run into this problem, templates describe what should be created rathen than using instances directly.

Comment: Added the style to a ResourceDictionary and marked image's x:Shared="false"